# Socket streaming in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, inputstream

When continuously writing/reading sets of data through a socket, how do you recognize the end of 1 set, the start of the next set, and if the entire set is even in the stream for retrieval yet, and not just a piece of it?

To make things simple let's say I'm sending JSON strings through the socket. How do I know if the whole object is there, and get that object from start to finish so I can correctly read it? Keep in mind there may be more objects  behind this one.

Comment: Could you provide some code please?

Comment: If you use Jackson, you can tell a `JsonParser` to not automatically close the input stream when reading a JSON value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. If you use an `ObjectOutputStream` then Java takes care of this for you. Obviously this is Java specific and requires you to have a `ObjectInputStream` on the other side. It also expects that you send serializable objects to the other side. `String` however is a serializable object, and I would in general expect any data structure to be serializable.

Otherwise you will have to think of some kind of container format yourself. Nowadays it is also pretty common to use XML structures to serialize the data into. If you go to an even higher level you get to the point of using web-services.

Comment: "data container" may be a better name than "data structure" but the name stuck since college a long time ago...

Comment: Interesting, so by using the object input/output streams, they will ensure that I get a whole object or nothing? So they will make sure the whole object gets written and received, all together? So I don't need to worry about 1/2 objects?

Comment: The serialVersionUIDs must be the same. The classes don't need to be the same, and the 'instances' of course cannot possibly be the same.

Comment: You still need to use the right words. You wrote 'object instance' when you were talking about 'class version'.

Comment: You will have to worry about `IOException` of course, but you will have to handle transmission based errors anyway. Both systems must use the same class versions, or more precisely they must (de-)serialize to the same bytes. Normally this means that the `serialVersionUID` of the objects should be the same.

Comment: @EJP OK, OK, rewrote the comment :)

Comment: The 'serialVersionUID' of the *class* should be the same at both ends. You don't seem to get the point here.

Comment: @EJP no, just sleepy. OK, "the `serialVersionUID`s of the classes of the object instances send should be identical".